# How to efficiently select certain items from two lists using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have these 3 classes:

- Employee
- Student
- Person

Code:

```
public class Employee
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public long TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
    
public class Student
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public long TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
    
public class Person<br>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I create 4 Lists :

```
var studentList = new List<Student>();// fill the List with a lot of Stundents
var employeeList = new List<Student>(); // fill the List with a lot of employees
var personList1 = new List<Person>();
var personList2 = new List<Person>();
```

Select all students and employees

```
var allStudents = studentList.Select(a => a); // does not make a lot of sence but for testing 
var allEmployee = employeeList.Select(b => b);
```

I want to map allStudents to

```
personList1.AddRange(allStudents.Select(a => new Person()
            {
               Age = a.Age,
               Name = a.Name
            } ));
```

I want to get all Employees where the value of TimeStape is not mentioned in the allStundent List

```
var allEmployeesWithDifferentTimeStampThanStundent =
    allEmployee.Where(a => !allStudents.Select(b =>b.TimeStamp).Contains(a.TimeStamp));
```

mapping again

```
personList2.AddRange(allEmployeesWithDifferentTimeStampThanStundent.Select
(a => new Person()
    {
    Age = a.Age,
    Name = a.Name
    } ));
```

merge both lists

```
personList1.AddRange(personList2);
```

Is there a better and more efficient way to do this?

Comment: try to google "List linq join" :)

Comment: Just because C# has nice LINQ features does not mean you have to abandon classic OOP patterns altogether. It appears that for example if Student would inherit from person you could look at a student as a person and you would not need to select student=> person.

Comment: thats true .... but I just wanted to create an example to demonstrate my point .... this is not a real example :-)

Comment: I will add that: Student, Employee both should inherit from Person.

Comment: You told us what you done, but not what you're trying to do.
What is the purpose ? to merge to list with different timestamp property ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `personList2` variable appears only to be there as an intermediate for projecting to the `Person` type -- if that's the case, you could skip its creation and use query syntax like so:

```
var personsFromNonMatchingEmployees =
    from employee in allEmployee
    join student in allStudents
    on employee.TimeStamp equals student.TimeStamp into studentsWithMatchingTimeStamp
    where !studentsWithMatchingTimeStamp.Any()
    select new Person { Age = employee.Age, Name = employee.Name };

personList1.AddRange(personsFromNonMatchingEmployees);
```

This is similar to the other GroupJoin approach since the compiler translates the above into a GroupJoin call. The use of join/group-join necessarily performs better than the `Where..Contains` approach since it makes use of hashing - in other words, it's an algorithmic Big-O improvement that should be quite noticeable for any more than a few Student or Employee instances.

By selecting the `new Person` object in the query, I'm able to bypass the `personList2` list altogether. I find that I'm almost always able to eliminate temporary lists by doing selects like this that project to the type that I'm really interested in. I also left out the `()` on the `new Person { .. }` since the compiler doesn't require it.

Shy of changing up the inheritance and making Employee : Person & Student : Person, I don't think there's much more to improve.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GroupJoin` to find all employees without a matching `Student` record with the same timestamp:

```
var employeesDiffTS = allEmployee
    .GroupJoin(allStudents, e => e.TimeStamp, s => s.TimeStamp, (e, students) => new { Emp = e, HasMatch = students.Any() })
    .Where(em => !em.HasMatch)
    .Select(em => em.Emp)

personList2.AddRange(employeeDiffTS.Select(a => new Person { Age = a.Age, Name = a.Name }));

personList1.AddRange(personList2);
```